# Multinode installation with swift using devstack

Tags: installation, openstack, openstack-swift, devstack

I'm trying multinode installation using devstack, but my object storage doesn't appear in the Horizon dashboard, How do we setup two nodes (controller and object storage) such that my controller knows about the the container service running on another host using devstack.

Comment: I have changed a tag, assuming that your question is *not* about the [Swift programming language](https://developer.apple.com/swift/).

Comment: Oh yeah, Sorry my bad.

Comment: devstack have a lot of automation. I'm not sure if you'll be able to do that. Have you tried asking on http://ask.openstack.org/ ? By container you mean lxc container, docker, ... ?

Comment: Yep, I did but no reply so far. and by container i mean the container service (Swift )of Openstack for object storage.